# How to detect constant keypress with Python TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm working on a Python Minigame similar to *"Achievement Unlocked"* where the player must move around the "map" (or level) to complete different tasks. The only issue is, I've been stuck for several days trying to detect a constant key press. I need to detect when a movement key is pressed, and while that key is held down, I need to move the character model in that direction until the key is released.

Currently, my code detects a keypress, but then shoots my character in the movement direction until the recursion limit is reached, where it then stops. It also immediately says that the key is released, even if it is still held down.

I am a beginner to Python, and searching for answers to this question has netted no results so far. I would appreciate any help you all could provide.

Thank you all so much!

```
# Import Tkinter and Keyboard
from tkinter import *

# Create Window
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

# Create Background and Walls
background = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000, fill='gray')
ground = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 840, 1000, 1000, fill='black')
leftwall = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 1000, fill='black')
rightwall = canvas.create_rectangle(970, 0, 1000, 1000, fill='black')
skybox = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 25, fill='black')

# Create Character Model
character = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill='lightblue')

# Set Character start position
canvas.move(character, 500, 500)

# Get Character Position
x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
xpos = ((x1 - x0) / 2) + x0
ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0

# Global Variables
is_key_up = True
contact = False


# Define Movements
def move(whatkey):
    global is_key_up

    if whatkey == "w" and is_key_up == False:
        canvas.move(character, 0, -10)
        root.after(1000, move(whatkey))
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    elif whatkey == "a" and is_key_up == False:
        canvas.move(character, -10, 0)
        root.after(1000, move(whatkey))
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    elif whatkey == "d" and is_key_up == False:
        canvas.move(character, 10, 0)
        root.after(1000, move(whatkey))
        xbounds()
        ybounds()


# Run Detection for if a key is released after being held (This is where I need help, I think)
def downkey(event):
    global is_key_up

    is_key_up = False
    print("Key Pressed")
    print(event.char)
    whatkey = event.char
    move(whatkey)


def upkey(event):
    global is_key_up, whatkey

    print("Key Released\n")
    is_key_up = True
    whatkey = event.char


# Apply constant downwards force while above y co-ords of 'ground'
def gravity():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0
    canvas.move(character, 0, 10)
    if ypos >= 800:
        root.after(500, anti)
    elif ypos <= 800 and contact == False:
        root.after(500, gravity)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()
    else:
        print("Gravity Error")


# Stop gravity when hitting 'ground' (Implement platform detection at a later date)
def anti():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0
    canvas.move(character, 0, 0)
    if ypos <= 800:
        root.after(500, gravity)
    else:
        root.after(500, anti)
    xbounds()
    ybounds()


# Set bounds of screen, left/right
def xbounds():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    if x0 <= 25:
        print("Horizontal Contact, Left!")
        canvas.coords(character, 25, y0, 75, y1)
    elif x1 >= 975:
        print("Horizontal Contact, Right!")
        canvas.coords(character, 900, y0, 950, y1)


def ybounds():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    if y0 <= 25:
        print("Vertical Contact, Upper!")
        canvas.coords(character, x0, 25, x1, 75)
    elif y1 >= 975:
        print("Vertical Contact, Lower!")
        canvas.coords(character, x0, 925, x1, 975)


# Implement Gravity
root.after(500, gravity)

# Bind keys
root.bind('<KeyPress>', downkey)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', upkey)

# Focus
root.focus_set()

# Loop indefinitely
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.after(1000, move(whatkey))` is calling `move()` *right now*, and doing absolutely nothing one second later (since the function didn't return anything, and therefore None is being passed to `.after()`).

Comment: As @ jasonharper said change `root.after(1000, move(whatkey))` to `root.after(1000, move, whatkey)`

Comment: In response to @jasonharper and @TheLizzard: Changing the ```root.after(1000, move(whatkey)``` to ```root.after(1000, move, whatkey)``` doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately. Holding still only returns a press and release, with only a single increment of movement; I am on MacOS if that's important (I saw a previous thread about how Mac is odd with registering keypresses.)